# How to create a data preprocessing pipeline in pytorch outside the Dataloader class?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, pipeline, torch, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to make a model for data with 40 features which have to classified into 10 classes. I am new to PyTorch and this is my first project in it.

I am given a custom Dataset class (**which I am not allowed to change**) which is as follows:

```
class MyData(Dataset):
    def _init_(self, mode):
        with open(mode+'.pkl', 'rb') as handle:
            data = pickle.load(handle)
            self.X = data['x'].astype('float')
            self.y = data['y'].astype('long')

    def _len_(self):
        return len(self.X)

    def _getitem_(self, idx):
        if torch.is_tensor(idx):
            idx = idx.tolist()

        sample = (self.X[idx], self.y[idx])

        return sample
```

I have done some preprocessing on the data like normalization and then trained and saved the model. As I wasn't allowed to change the dataset class, I made the changes outside of it and then used the `DataLoader` method. The preprocessing is as follows :

```
train_data=MyData("train")
features, labels = train_data[:]

df = pd.DataFrame(features)

x = df.values
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)

input_array = x_scaled
output_array = labels

inputs = torch.Tensor(input_array)
targets = torch.Tensor(output_array).type(torch.LongTensor)
dataset = TensorDataset(inputs, targets)
train_ds, val_ds = random_split(dataset, [3300, 300])


batch_size = 300
n_epochs = 200
log_interval = 10
train_losses = []
train_counter = []
test_losses = []

train_loader = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle=True)
val_loader = DataLoader(val_ds, batch_size)
test_counter = [i*len(train_loader.dataset) for i in range(n_epochs + 1)]
```

After this I define the training and testing functions ( and remove the print statements as the autograder will not be able to grade my assignment if I do so) as follows:

```
def train(epoch):
  model.train()
  for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(data.double())
    loss = criterion(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if batch_idx % log_interval == 0:
      train_losses.append(loss.item())
      train_counter.append(
        (batch_idx*32) + ((epoch-1)*len(train_loader.dataset)))
    save_model(model)

def test():
  model.eval()
  test_loss = 0
  correct = 0
  with torch.no_grad():
    for data, target in val_loader:
      output = model(data.double())
      test_loss += criterion(output, target).item()
      pred = output.data.max(1, keepdim=True)[1]
      correct += pred.eq(target.data.view_as(pred)).sum()
  test_loss /= len(val_loader.dataset)
  test_losses.append(test_loss)
  
test()
for epoch in range(1, n_epochs + 1):
  train(epoch)
  test()
```

Even after doing that, the autograder is still not able to grade my code. I mainly think it's because maybe I am making an error with how I input the data to the model but I am not able to narrow down to what exactly is the problem and how do I correct it. As I'm new to pytorch, I was looking at how to do the preprocessing but all of them involved the Dataset Class so I'm not sure how to go about it.

My model is as follows:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        #self.flatten=nn.Flatten()

        self.net_stack=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=40, out_channels=256, kernel_size=1, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=1),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(256, affine=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=1, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=1),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(128, affine=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=1, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=1),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(64, affine=True),
            nn.Conv1d(in_channels=64, out_channels=32, kernel_size=1, stride=2), #applying batch norm
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool1d(kernel_size=1),
            nn.Dropout(p=0.1),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(32, affine=True),
            nn.Flatten(),
            nn.Linear(32, 10),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1)).double()

    def forward(self,x):
        # result=self.net_stack(x[None])
        x=x.double()
        result=self.net_stack(x[:, :, None]).double()
        print(result.size())
        return result
```

One instruction I've got is that they've written:

```
# Please make sure we can load your model with:
# model = MyModel()
# This means you must give default values to all parameters you may wish to set, such as output size.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it within the training loop

```py
for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
   # you can do something here to manipulate your input
   data = transform(data)
   data.to('cuda') # Move to gpu, i noticed you didnt do it in your training loop

   # Forward pass
   output = model(data)
```